# Regular expression - Match where not between certain characters

Tags: php, regex, string

I've never used look ahead and look behind in regular expressions before, so I'm struggling with this one.

Given a string like this:

```
|'a'|$b|'...|...'|'c'|$d|
```

What I want to do is explode by the character | and get everything between them.

Now if the string was:

```
|'a'|$b|'......'|'c'|$d|
```

That would be fine, I wouldn't even need a regular expression, I could just do `explode("|", $str)` and get an array of items.

But if I introduce that pipe character into that middle string it throws the whole thing.

So what I've tried so far is to come up with a regular expression that matches the pipe character | when it doesn't have a quote to the left and doesn't have a quote to the right, but it's not going very well.

So far all I've managed is to match the | when there is no quote directly either side, e.g. left:

```
/(?<!([']))\|/
```

When I try and introduce something like `(.*?)` into it to check if there is anything between the quote and the |, it gives me an error about "lookbehinds need to be zero-width" (this is on http://regex101.com)

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this? As I can forsee me sitting here for hours messing around with this.

Cheers.

Comment: You could also just use [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) with appropriate parameters for delimiter and quote character.

Comment: This isn't a job for regex. You need to actually parse the string.

Comment: **REGULAR** expressions are not suitable for parsing IRREGULAR inputs.

Comment: @mario Thanks, that works well for that example. Unfortuntely not for when it becomes a bit more complex, such as: 

'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'|reverse|chomp:15:'...|...'|upper

Is there anything I can alter in the function call which will make that kind of example work do you think? Or am I going to have to re-think this from the beginning?

Comment: Do you have control over what is generating the initial string? Might be easier to rethink that part.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm playing around with template engines and trying to come up with a way to call various methods with parameters on strings/variables/etc... Similar to this sort of thing: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html

Comment: If you have to be able to take the string apart later, could you not just json_encode() and then json_decode() it? Or, in twig, http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html Or, join with something you are very unlikely to find in a real string, like %%

Comment: A simple regex can do this but you have to be consistent with the rules. Are fields separated by pipes or not? Can fields be single quoted or not quoted? Like `|I am a field 'that is quoted improperly' end of field|` is a witch hunt. I mean its doable but not too clear.

Comment: I think for the time being I'm just going to say if that character appears inside a string then it'll have to be escaped. /(?<!\\\\)\|/

Answer (score 0):

you can sort of do this without look-behind but rather just using look-ahead. We can look ahead for an even number of quotes from our pipe:

```
\|.*?(?=\|)(?=[^']*?(?:[^']*?'[^']*?')*[^']*?$)
```

This doesn't capture the trailing pipe of the group as, at least with my regex tool returning all matches, it won't double count the pipe as the end separator and start separator.
Running the above gave me: `|'a'` `|$b` `|'...|...'` `|'c'` `|$d`